# jquery two divs using 'hover' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

```
$('img.clientImage').live('hover', function () {
    if ($('div#ClientImageHover').length > 0) {
        $('div#ClientImageHover').remove();
    } else {
        $('<div id="ClientImageHover">Change Image</div>').insertAfter($(this));
        $('div#ClientImageHover').css({ 'top': $(this).position().top });
    }
})
```

Now what happens if I hover over `#ClientImageHover`. You guessed it, it will start flickering quickly on and off. Because there's a `mouseout` event on `.clientImage`.
I need to create the element here and append it after the `img` then position it on top of it. This is working correctly, but I am having issues when hovering over `#ClientImageHover`. How can I keep showing this div normally when the mouse is over it and keep everything as it currently is?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not contain both of them inside a common parent and bind the hover event to that instead?

Comment: Well the `img` is repeated on many many different pages. I think that way I would save myself from repeating a `<div>` line on each page. and just create/remove the element from the dom whenever needed.

Comment: it would be batter to create the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, do something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy9Xg/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="clientImage"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.container').live('hover', function () {
    if ($('div#ClientImageHover').length > 0) {
        $('div#ClientImageHover').remove();
    } else {
        $('<div id="ClientImageHover">Change Image</div>').appendTo($(this));
        $('div#ClientImageHover').css({ 'top': $(this).position().top });
    }
});
```

Comment: yup this would work. thanks (I will wait a bit to check if this could be done without adding a container, but otherwise this solved it + 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could break it up to use .mouseenter() and.mouseleave(). Use .mouseenter() on `img.clientImage` and then only remove it on `$('div#ClientImageHover').mouseleave();`

http://jsfiddle.net/gkkxG/

Comment: I need to remove it on `.clientImage` `mouseleave` and show it on `.clientImage` `mouseenter`. And only keep `#ClientImageHover` displayed when the mouse is over it only removing it when its out of `.clientImage`